# How do i check the load of an external font

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very strange problem and I'm not even sure if its the right angle but here comes the setup:

link to a google font in the head;

`onload: function x()` to render the font in a canvas;

```
onclick: x();
```

since the `onload` renders the text in a standard font and the `onclick` execution of the same function work perfectly, I'm thinking the font is not fully loaded on the first execution.
so i was wondering if there was a way to check the loading progress of an external font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Google Fonts API, particularly the section ['Acting on events'](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader#events)?

Answer (score 0):

```
WebFontConfig = {
  google: {
    families: [ 'Tangerine', 'Cantarell' ]
  },
  typekit: {
    id: 'myKitId'
  },
  loading: function() {
    // do something
  },
  fontloading: function(fontFamily, fontDescription) {
    // do something
  },
  fontactive: function(fontFamily, fontDescription) {
    // do something
  },
  fontinactive: function(fontFamily, fontDescription) {
    // do something
  },
  active: function() {
    // do something
  },
  inactive: function() {
    // do something
  }
};

(function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
            '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })();
```